# Building a Ruby stack on Windows Server: msvcrt-ruby18.dll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mongrel

I'm attempting to run mongrel_rails, but I get the following:

```
    the program can't start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing from your computer
```

Ruby then gives me the following:

```
    C:\Users\Administrator>mongrel_rails
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 126: The s
    pecified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mong
    rel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/http11.so (LoadError)
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require
    '
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/m
    ongrel.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require
    '
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require
    '
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/m
    ongrel_rails:11:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby193/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
            from C:/Ruby193/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `<main>'
```

I've tried to uninstall json and reinstall with --version=ruby to no avail.  I've also tried using mongrel --pre, which results in a different set of errors:

```
    NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be remove
    d on or after 2011-11-01.
    Gem::SourceIndex#each called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gem_plugin
    -0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:112.
    !!! Path to log file not valid: log/mongrel.log
    mongrel::start reported an error. Use mongrel_rails mongrel::start -h to get hel
    p.
```

My stack looks like this:

```
    Ruby 1.9.3p0
    Windows Server 2008 R2

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    actionmailer (3.2.1)
    actionpack (3.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.1)
    activerecord (3.2.1)
    activeresource (3.2.1)
    activesupport (3.2.1)
    arel (3.0.0)
    bigdecimal (1.1.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    bundler (1.0.22)
    cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    daemons (1.1.8)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.0)
    fastthread (1.0.7)
    gem_plugin (0.2.3)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    io-console (0.3)
    journey (1.0.1)
    jquery-rails (2.0.0)
    json (1.6.5)
    mail (2.4.1)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    minitest (2.5.1)
    mongrel (1.2.0.pre2 x86-mingw32)
    mongrel_service (0.4.0)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.1)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
    rack-test (0.6.1)
    rails (3.2.1)
    railties (3.2.1)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdiscount (1.6.8)
    rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.2.4)
    sprockets (2.3.1, 2.1.2)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5 x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
```

Has anyone ever encountered this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you're trying to install binary gems for Mongrel on Ruby 1.9.3 when mongrel binaries only work for Ruby 1.8.x

Mongrel hasn't been updated to work with latest Ruby or Rails, so please avoid using it at this time.

You can use Thin as alternative:

```
gem install eventmachine --pre
gem install thin
```

The pre-installation of eventmachine pre-release version is required since latest stable 0.12 does not work with Ruby 1.9.x on Windows.

Also, if you're using a version of Windows Server, please ensure Ruby executable (`ruby.exe`) is added to the DEP exclusion list:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-dep_segfault

Comment: Thanks so much Luis, that was very helpful.  Off to Thin I go!