# Can't run Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem when i try to run the server using **rails s**

I'm using Windows, and this is the return:

```
C:\Blog\MyBlog>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `pidfile_process_status'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:340:in `check_pid!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:246:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Blog\MyBlog>
```

My gemfile:

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> ```
> gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
>
> # Bundle edge Rails instead:
> # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
>
> gem 'sqlite3'
>
>
> # Gems used only for assets and not required
> # in production environments by default.
> group :assets do
>   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
>   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
>
>   # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
>   # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
>
>   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
> end
>
> gem 'jquery-rails'
>
> # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
> # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
>
> # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
> # gem 'jbuilder'
>
> # Use unicorn as the app server
> # gem 'unicorn'
>
> # Deploy with Capistrano
> # gem 'capistrano'
>
> # To use debugger
> # gem 'debugger'
> ```

**ruby** 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32], **Rails** 3.2.12 ,**Gem** 1.8.25

***Sorry for my english people***

## EDITED

I try using mongrel but i get the next in the cmd:

```
C:\Blog\MyBlog>rails s mongrel
Exiting
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:1:in
`require': cannot load such file -- mongrel (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/mon
grel.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:
20:in `const_get'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:
20:in `block in get'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:
20:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:
20:in `inject'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:
20:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:2
72:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/comma
nds/server.rb:59:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: No problems with `bundle`?

Comment: Maybe it can help you : 
http://pullmonkey.com/2008/02/19/errno-einval-invalid-argument/

Comment: I made 'bundle install' but nothing change, if it's that what you say, i see what you say, senayar, but it's not the case, i am not using anything called 'mongrel'... Sorry, im a newbie with all this (ruby, and ror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows and Rails doesn't work usually as well as in other environments. Best workaround Webbrick problems in Windows with Rails is to install another server for development. Mongrel is a good alternative. To install it:

```
gem install mongrel
```

And then to start the server

```
rails s mongrel
```

Comment: I have a problem with that option. I'll edit the question with the information.

Comment: Try to put `gem mongrel` in your Gemfile.

Comment: "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:12:in `require': 126: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.   - C:/Ruby193/
lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/http11.so (LoadError)" ... I put "gem 'mongrel'" on my gemfile but that is what i get... (Windows is in spanish, sorry)

Comment: Well, it seems that after Ruby 1.8.X, Mongrel doesn't work on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294858/building-a-ruby-stack-on-windows-server-msvcrt-ruby18-dll. Try with the solution of that post. And don't worry for the language, I know spanish =P.

Comment: @Tomas Also I recommend you to install a Linux if you want to develop seriously with Rails. Windows developers sometimes runs into different and unexplained issues, apart from unmanteined libraries for that environment.

Comment: Sorry for my late, i'll install linux then, thanks you anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Trying adding a random  no (for eg., 6532) to the tmp/pids/server.pid file and then start the webricks

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! I'm using Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. I discovered the easiest fix is actually just to delete the existing pid file in the application folder:

```
del tmp\pids\*.*
```

Found this solution referring to this resource: [https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/544][1]